# Android Wear: Do the wearable and handheld module permissions have to match exactly?

Tags: android, android-manifest, wear-os

I am creating an app that uses the `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions on a handheld device which does all of the heavy lifting of the application. The handheld device then sends off data to a wearable device that doesn't really do much else besides receive the data and display it. According to the Android Documentation for [Packaging Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#Studio), they say:

> Include all the permissions declared in the manifest file of the
>   wearable app module in the manifest file of the handheld app module.

If I understand this correctly, since the wearable itself doesn't use any Android features that require permissions, I do not have to include anything else in the handheld `AndroidManifest.xml` file. However, I've come across others saying that the `AndroidManifest.xml` files of both modules must match exactly in their permissions, or you could encounter packaging errors. Although this isn't the case for me, I was wondering if someone could clear up this up.

Comment: I've heard that they need to match exactly

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on the handheld should be a superset of the ones on the wear; in other words, any permission required on the wear side needs to be present on the handheld but not the other way around.